# Scala Pattern Matching with Implicit

Tags: scala

I have this simple code

```
val x = Some((10, "foo"))
x.map{case (a, b) => println(s"$a $b")}
```

this works but I want `a` and `b` to be implicit. I can do this like

```
x.map{case f => implicit val a = f._1; implicit val b = f._2; println(s"$a $b")}
```

But this is too verbose. I wonder if there is a shorter way to achieve what I want.

The reason why I want a and b to be implicit is that a and b are passed to many functions as implicit parameters.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the implicits?

Comment: The values a and b are passed to many functions implicitly.